# mySQL, Stored Procedure, double COUNT not working (w/SQLfiddle)

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have this SQL

```
   SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT `ct`.`content_type_id`) AS `type_count`
        , COUNT(`content_id`) AS `content_count`
     FROM `user_to_content` `uc`
     JOIN `content` `c` USING (`content_id`)
     JOIN `content_type` `ct` USING (`content_type_id`)
    WHERE `user_id`= 1;
```

I am trying to get 2 numbers from the same table at the same time.

This [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db67e9/2) file shows the above SQL working...

However I am unable to get the SP version to work.
I can't seem to get SQLfiddle to work with SP (maybe some can show me how), so [here](http://pastebin.com/mWPaZK0z) is the SP at pastebin...

Anyway, the SP will not "compile" with the second COUNT command...

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 24
```

This is line 24

```
DECLARE $type_count    TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
```

My work around on this is too call the COUNT on the table twice. I'd rather not.

Comment: Dumb question, but what happens if you try it without the dollar sign?  This tutorial might help:  http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,358569

Comment: The '$' is just my way of keeping track of internal variables to the SP. Nothing more. They are not required by mySQL nor the SP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example with some modifications:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_system_content_badges`
(  IN `$user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED
 , IN `$content_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED
 , IN `$content_type_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED
)
BEGIN
  -- DECLARE $type_count    TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
  -- DECLARE $content_count TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;

  DECLARE `$type_count`    INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE `$content_count` INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;

  -- How many pieces of content has this person consumed
  -- Is there 4 unique kinds as well

  -- SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT `ct`.`content_type_id`) INTO $type_count
  --      , COUNT(`content_id`) INTO $content_count

  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ct`.`content_type_id`), COUNT(`c`.`content_id`)
    INTO `$type_count`, `$content_count`
  FROM `user_to_content` `uc`
    JOIN `content` `c` USING (`content_id`)
    JOIN `content_type` `ct` USING (`content_type_id`)
  WHERE `user_id`= `$user_id`;
  SELECT `$type_count` 'TYPE_COUNT', `$content_count` 'CONTENT_COUNT';
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d93de/1)</kbd>